# android Html.TagHandler class - can i override tags functionality

Tags: android

I want to understand how the tagHandler works. lets say i have in html a tag  and i want override what it does.  i mean its expected it will add a new line. but lets say i want it to instead print text.  So here is what i have tried:

```
public class MyTagHandler implements Html.TagHandler {
       @Override
       public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output,
                             XMLReader xmlReader) {

           if(tag.equals("br")) && !opening) output.append("hello world");
       }
   }
```

then i run it like this:

```
Html.fromHtml(myHTMLString,null,new MyTagHandler());
```

and it seems ok but i dont want it to print a new line. i want to actually override what the tag 
 does. so it should only print "hello world" nothing else. is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do this. I have to rename `</br>` to a custom tag like so:

```
myHTML.replaceAll("</br>","</customTag>").replaceAll("<br>","<customTag>");
```

Then, in my handler I can look for that `customTag` (which does nothing) and make it do something.

```
 public class UlTagHandler implements Html.TagHandler {
        //for ul in nougat and up this tagHandler is completely ignored
        @Override
        public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output,
                              XMLReader xmlReader) {
      
            if (tag.equals("customtag") && opening)
                output.append("do whatever you want");
            if (tag.equals("customtag") && !opening)
                output.append("closed tag, do whatever you want");
        }
    }
```